# sharetribe sh: indexer: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharetribe

I just clone https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe open source project, I install every gem and when I try to run:

```
bundle exec rake ts:index
```

I get the following error:

> WARN You specified server rendering JS file:
>   app/assets/webpack/server-bundle.js, but it cannot be read. You may
>   set the server_bundle_js_file in your configuration to be "" to avoid
>   this warning You specified server rendering JS file:
>   app/assets/webpack/server-bundle.js, but it cannot be read. You may
>   set the server_bundle_js_file in your configuration to be "" to avoid
>   this warning Generating configuration to
>   /Users/jeanosorio/Repos/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf
>   DEBUG   SQL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE (handler LIKE
>   ('--- !ruby/object:ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::%') AND locked_at IS NULL
>   AND locked_by IS NULL AND failed_at IS NULL) sh: indexer: command not
>   found

And I can't make it work.

Comment: Have you tried “set the server_bundle_js_file in your configuration to be "" to avoid this warning”?

Comment: this "error" you show is just a warning. The title of your post has a different error `sh: indexer: command not found`

Comment: @mudasobwa I can't find this file

Comment: @maxpleaner the last line of the "warning" said sh: indexer: command not found

Answer (score 2):

Have come across this myself, so for anyone seeing this error, problem is likely that your node version is different from the current Sharetribe version.

Use NVM to manage it.  At time of writing, Node version for Sharetribe was 6.9.

`$ NVM use 6.9`

Then delete and reinstall node_modules

`$ rm -rf client/node_modules && npm install`

That should do it.